# How to correctly upload excel and word documents using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am using javascript file reader api to read the file and upload. When a user select ms excel documents the extensions become `vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` 
I am using laravel for uploading the file. It uploads the file using this extensions(`vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`) but this uploaded file is not readable at all.

Here is my php code that I am using to upload to a file

```
       $explodedFile= explode(',', $request->file);
        $file=$explodedFile[1];
        $file=base64_decode($file);
        $ext=substr($request->file, 5, strpos($request->file, ';')-5);
        $ext=explode('/', $ext);
        $ext=$ext[1];
        $fileName= str_random().'.'.$ext;
        $path=public_path().'/uploads/'.$fileName;
        file_put_contents($path, $file);
```

Main problem is all types of words, excel documents is not readable from the browser. What can I do to read the file?

Thank you.

Comment: If you say readable  do you meen that the browser should show the content, as if you would open it in word or excel?

Comment: Sorry, I am giving this docs as downloadable files and when users download they see this long extensions and cannot open the file in the local pc. Thank you

Comment: Did you test if you upload a local file to the server if the file content is changed? Just download it with ftp and do a `comp`

Comment: I am testing in my localhost. File contents seems to be ok but the extensions is the problem